# COUNT function and INNER JOIN on multiple tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, count

This is so complicated (for me) because I usually only work with single table and simple queries (SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE), but now I am in a situation where I am stuck.

- What I am trying to archive is that: when a project manager logged-into his/her account, a grid-view will show a quick overview for all of his/her projects (id, created date, name and how many files are in pending) like below picture:

[image]

- 3 tables will be involved are:

[image]

- Sample data for manager_id = 11:

[image]

I tried this query but it not worked, it seems to display all columns right but the COUNT pending files column (assume the manager_id = 11)

```
SELECT COUNT(file_id) as 'Pending files', projects.project_id, projects.project_name, projects.status, projects.start_date
FROM ((project_manager 
INNER JOIN files 
ON project_manager.mag_id = files.manager_id AND project_manager.mag_id = 11 AND file_status = 'Pending')
INNER JOIN projects
ON projects.project_id = project_manager.project_id)
GROUP BY projects.project_id, projects.project_name, projects.status, projects.start_date
ORDER BY projects.status, projects.start_date DESC
```

- my query result:

[image]

I need help with a correct query and if you can explain it a little bit that would be much appreciated!

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @ActiveHigh I need a correct query to display what I am trying to archive LOL

Comment: You want to COUNT fileid only when the file_status is pending?Use `COUNT(CASE WHEN file_status='pending' THEN file_id ELSE 0 END)`

Comment: @Mihai Yes, I want to COUNT whatever so that it will show how many file is on 'pending', if there is not any file with file_status = 'Pending" then I want to display 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include project_id in your Join to the files table and use a left join -

```
SELECT COUNT(file_id) as 'Pending files', projects.project_id, projects.project_name, projects.status, projects.start_date

FROM ((project_manager 
LEFT JOIN files 
ON project_manager.mag_id = files.manager_id AND project_manager.mag_id = 11 AND file_status = 'Pending' AND project_manager.project_Id = files.project_id )
INNER JOIN projects
ON projects.project_id = project_manager.project_id)

WHERE project_manager.mag_id = 11
GROUP BY projects.project_id, projects.project_name, projects.status, projects.start_date
ORDER BY projects.status, projects.start_date DESC
```

Comment: I just tested and it works correctly. I need some explanations please if you can, how you come up with that query, where to start, what is step 1, step 2 ... because I always have a hard time with SQL quires on multiple tables

Comment: Essentially I would have started with project_manager table as you did, then get all the projects associated with the manager hence INNER JOIN to projects on the project_id. Next you are interested in only files that are pending for that manager and project hence in your join condition you would need both- your  manager_id and project_id - along with the condition file_status = 'Pending. It is a LEFT JOIN because you don't want to lose any rows from the other two tables that do not have any pending files. Finally count and group bys. Count(file_id) does not include nulls hence you get ur reslt

Comment: Hey I got problem, this query will displays all projects of all managers, so something is not right with the logic, I need it only display projects that belong to 1 current logged manager (for example project_manager.mag_id = 11).

Comment: Just add the project_manager.mag_id = 11 in your where clause. Updated in answer.

Comment: Thanks so much for the instant assistance.